# How to use $(this) in $scope functions on Angular JS + jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I just wanted to ask why `$(this)` selector doesn't work inside $scope functions in Angular JS + jQuery.

I have this sample code:

[Javascript]

```
$scope.startTimer = function() {
     $(this).hide();
}
```

[HTML]

```
<button ng-click="startTimer()">
```

I've tried doing it like this but still doesn't work:

[Javascript]

```
$scope.startTimer = function(btn) {
     $(btn).hide();
}
```

[HTML]

```
<button ng-click="startTimer(this)">
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 4):

do it with angular way...

[HTML]

```
<button ng-click="startTimer()" ng-hide="btnHide">
```

[Javascript]

```
$scope.startTimer = function(btn) {
     btnHide = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a scope variable inside the markup in angular

```
<div ng-init="hideButton:false">
    <button ng-click="hideButton=true" ng-hide="hideButton">
</div>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7dp0whqk/)